# How to get date (time) in specific format for C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm creating C# application. It should save to file (among others) today's date (time) in different formats, e.g. in one line there should be only a day, in a second month and a year splitted by `/`, etc.

I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) article about standard and custom date formats, but didn't find that what I wanted.

I PHP I have got a function `date()`. It can return me a date in specified by me format, like:

`date('l');` - day name (e.g. Monday)

`date('h:i:s A');` - hours:minuts:second PM/AM

That's fine, because I can alone specify separator, etc. Is there any equvalent solution to this one in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a result same as `date('l')` method, you can use [`dddd` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ddddSpecifier) with an english-based culture (eg: [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)) like;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Sunday
```

or you can use [`DayOfWeek` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) which is not localized;

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek // Sunday
```

If you want to get a result same as `date('h:i:s A')` method, you can use custom date and time format with `InvariantCulture` like;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to get a result as `11-16/2014`, (since we don't know about your culture) you can format your string with escaping seperators like;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'-'dd'/'yyyy"); // 11-16/2014
```

Remember, [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with the current culture date separator*. If you use it without any `IFormatProvider`, it will replace itself your `CurrentCulture`'s [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}", 
               date);
```

Comment: DateTime date = DateTime.Now

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) for the current time and [ToString with a format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, to output "11-16/2014" from the current time on this day 16 November 2014:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM-dd\/yyyy")
```

Comment: That gives me 11-16-2014 not 11-16/2014 as I excepted

Comment: Yes, I was getting the same results as you when using Polish culture but my edited answer with the "/" as a literal will now give you what you want. It was because "/" is a Custom Format Specifier in the format string, as detailed in the MSDN page I linked to. The point anyway is to teach a man to fish not give him a fish :)

Answer (score 0):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

You can pretty much format it any way you like.

DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd/yy") should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I told I read that already. Please tell me, what should I write to get date of today in this format: 11-16/2014 ?